# Postgres update vs default

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is faster in Postgres - create column with default value or create nullable column and manually update column with constant value?

I am asking because update in Postgres is insert and delete using vacuum. Does the same apply to creating column with default?

Comment: You should test it, but I would assume that updating would be slower.

Comment: I would push for use case dictating which one to implement. If it's just a curiosity than you can ignore this comment. I don't know which is faster.

Comment: I would think that a nullable column with a default of null and then a manual update will be more expensive than setting a default on creation. But unless you have billions of rows to update then I don't think it will matter which way you do it.

Comment: What use case do you have in mind that you think the difference would matter?

Comment: If you want a default value, simply specify it.

Answer (score 0):

From PostgreSQL v11 on, creating a column with a non-NULL default will not rewrite the table any more, so it will be very fast.

Even before that, the operation will probably be fester, since it rewrites the whole table at once rather than updating rows one by one (I didn't test this). The disadvantage in this case is that rewriting the table will block concurrent `SELECT`s on the table, while an `UPDATE` won't.

Comment: Update in Postgres is insert and delete using vacuum.
Does the same apply to creating column with default?

Comment: No - as I wrote, either it is just a metadata change (v11 and higher) or a rewrite of the whole table (earlier versions). Quite different from and update. For one, it won't make the table larger.

Comment: @Vova: It should be noted that the optimisation only applies to non-volatile default expressions. Else (like for `current_timestamp`) it still triggers a table rewrite.